# bad import of http on flutter for web

Tags: http, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

i was attempting to make an http request to a server, but when i import the package http the vs code print the next error:

```
Unable to find modules for some sources, this is usually the result of either a
bad import, a missing dependency in a package (or possibly a dev_dependency
needs to move to a real dependency), or a build failure (if importing a
generated file).

Please check the following imports:

`import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;` from fcfm_pa|lib/src/pages/registro_page.dart at 5:1
```

someone knows what's happen?

Comment: The easiest way that I was able to solve this problem was to change from beta channel to master channel. I would suggest anyone facing this issue to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You should update your **pubspec.yaml** file with the following library declaration:

```
dependencies:
  http: ^0.12.0+4
```

and then import the library. After doing so, make sure to do over the terminal:

```
flutter pub get
```

and maybe even `flutter clean` to make sure you have everything correctly. Make a new build and you should be good to go.

Comment: now i get the next error "Failed to build application for the Web."

Comment: could you add your "flutter doctor -v" over your answer? So we can know your specific version, etc

Answer (score 1):

If you are on beta channel, this is an issue that occurs.

Try `flutter channel master` and then run the app again, this issue should not appear anymore.